# Динамический массив указателей на объект C++

Tags: c++

Итак, цель - сделать одномерный динамический массив с указателями на объекты.
В голову приходит сделать так:

```
int n = 10;
AbstractClass **arr = new AbstractClass* [n];
```

Но, как вы уже поняли (и видите), это не работает. Я туплю в чем-то очевидном. Кто видит, в чем?

Comment: А что не так7 У меня всё работает: http://ideone.com/LF071c

Comment: Приведите ваше сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Проверка синтаксиса ругается на оператор присваивания. Выкидывает ошибку `Error: no operator "=" matches this operands; operand types are: Neuron = Neuron **`. Среда: Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Ваше сообщение упоминает какой-то не описанный в вопросе класс...

Comment: Тошо я сплю уже и туплю. Neuron == AbstractClass, в данном случае. Прошу прощения за путаницу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы не путаться сделайте с помощью псевдонима

```
typedef AbstractClass * AbstractClassPtr;

int n = 10;
AbstractClassPtr * arr = new AbstractClassPtr[n];
```